# Writing a LINQ result into a text file

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write the output of a LINQ query into a text file. For that I am using an extension method.

This is my LINQ query:

```
var group =
    from c in census_data
    group c by c.state into g
    join s in state_gdp on g.FirstOrDefault().state equals s.state
    orderby s.gdp descending
    select new
    {
        State = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        SavingsBalance = g.Average(x => x.savingsBalanceDouble),
        GDP = s.gdp
    };
```

This is my extension method:

```
public static class CSVWriter
{
    public static void write(this Enumerable e, string file)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
        {
            foreach (var i in e)
            {
                f.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting an error that says `System.Linq.Enumerable` does not have a `getEnumerator` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution can look like this:

```
var result =
    from c in census_data
    group c by c.state into g
    join s in state_gdp on g.FirstOrDefault().state equals s.state
    orderby s.gdp descending
    select new
    {
        State = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        SavingsBalance = g.Average(x => x.savingsBalanceDouble),
        GDP = s.gdp
    };

var buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.AppendLine("#key,name,sum,gdp");
result.ToList().ForEach(item => buffer.AppendLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", item.State, item.Count, item.SavingBalance, item.GDP)));
File.WriteAllText("d:\\temp\\file.csv", buffer.ToString());
```

---

You need to change `Enumerable` to `IEnumerable`. Since you are creating an anonymous object, your solution will transfer the list of anonymous objects (`IEnumerable<anonymous>`) to your function where you write the data to the file, but you will not be able to format the ouput as desired.

One possible solution would be to put the lines you want to write to the file to a string buffer and then write the text at once using the System.IO.File.WriteAllText method:

```
// test data
var data = new List<Int32> { 1, 20, 30, 40, 50, 70 };
// create a list of anonymous objects
var result = data.Select (d => new 
{
    Count = d,
    State = String.Format("Item {0}", d),
    SavingBalance = d * 10
});
// create the output text buffer
var buffer = new StringBuilder();
// add header line
buffer.AppendLine("#key,name,sum");
// add each result line
result.ToList().ForEach(item => buffer.AppendLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", item.Count, item.State, item.SavingBalance)));
// write to file
File.WriteAllText("d:\\temp\\file.csv", buffer.ToString());
```

The output is:

```
#key,name,sum
1,Item 1,10
20,Item 20,200
30,Item 30,300
40,Item 40,400
50,Item 50,500
70,Item 70,700
```

The solution which @aravol and @StephneKennedy mentioned will look like this:

```
public static class CSVWriter
{
    public static void write<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, string file)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
        {
            foreach (var i in e)
            {
                f.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
result.write<object>(file);
```

As already stated, the problem with this solution is that you can not format the output, because you are using the Object.ToString method and you can't format it (the default output looks something like `{ key = value, key = value, ... }`).

If you still want to transfer the result to another method, then create a typed class and create an object for every result entry (and then transfer the list). An example typed class can look like this:

```
public class Placeholder
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Index { get; set; }
    public Double Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your LINQ query to create a new object of `Placeholder`, instead of anonymous object:

```
// test data
var data = new List<Int32> { 1, 20, 30, 40, 50, 70 };
var result = data.Select (d => new Placeholder
{
    Key = d,
    Name = String.Format("Item {0}", d),
    Sum = d * 10.0m
}).ToList();
result.write<Placeholder>("d:\\temp\\file.csv");
```

And your extension method can directly use the `write(this IEnumerable<Placeholder>...)` or cast every object to use the class properties:

```
public static class CSVWriter
{
    public static void write<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, string file)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter f = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file))
        {
            foreach (var i in e)
            {
                f.WriteLine(((Placeholder)i).Sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "your solution will not work because you can not transfer the list of anonymous objects (IEnumerable<anonymous>) to your function where you write the data to the file." Yes you can and my example does just that - the compiler is smart enough to accept an anonymous T. The problem is that there is no ToString() available on the anonymous object to create the required output.

Comment: I like your first solution. But how can I select each entry attributes (state, count, ...)? Because in your test data there's just a list of integers, but my data is not like that

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have a look at the creation of the result and not the list. I have explicitly chose for the example three different data types in the result, to simulate your case. Then have a closer look at the line, that appends the text to the buffer. The `String.Format` is converting automatically every parameter to a string. Since you are writing to a text file, this is alright.

Comment: The list is only to simulate the creation of the result. The part that you need is actually just the creation of the buffer, the part where you fill it and then how you write the buffer to the file. In your case you should write `group.ToList()....`.

Comment: what I mean is that you created your result list from a List of integers. But my original data is an IEnumerable<T>. How can I extract the data into the result variable like you did with the integer list? I mean how can I do this `var result = data.Select (d => new 
{
    Count = d,
    State = String.Format("Item {0}", d),
    SavingBalance = d * 10
});` for the `IEnumerable`? In your list `d` is just an integer, but for me it is not. How can I access each attribute and assign its value to the proper key?

Comment: You already have this part in your example - it is the `var group = ...;`. I have updated my answer to match your code example, just renamed `group` to `result` in your original code.

Comment: now I understand. But this way the result should be calculated inside the extension method. This is not what I was trying to do. The extension method just should receive the result and format it into a text file.

Comment: You have many options. You could pass the buffer to your extension method, you can use the other two suggestions from my answer. The important thing to note is that you can't pass easily anonymous objects around.